# Seek bar, change path color from yellow to white

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have two questions:

1) how do I change the color of the seek bar (path) from yellow (the default color) to white. What I mean to say is, while I slide the thumb , it turns the line traversed from grey to yellow.  I want track/line to either remain grey or white..Basically I want just the thumb to move with no color change in the seek bar.

2)
How to change the thumb of seekbar from rectangle to circle/sphere/round shape.

any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I want to complete the answer from above for the people who are new to the system,

the missing xmls ( background_fill , progress_fill and progress could look like that for a gradient red

### progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item 
            android:id="@android:id/background" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/background_fill" />

        <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
           <clip android:drawable="@drawable/progress_fill" />
        </item>
  </layer-list>
```

### background_fill.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#FF555555" 
        android:centerColor="#FF555555"
        android:endColor="#FF555555" 
        android:angle="90" />

    <corners android:radius="5px" />

    <stroke 
        android:width="2dp" 
        android:color="#50999999" />

    <stroke 
        android:width="1dp" 
        android:color="#70555555" />
</shape>
```

### progress_fill.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#FF470000" 
        android:centerColor="#FFB80000"
        android:endColor="#FFFF4400" 
        android:angle="180" />

    <corners android:radius="5px" />

    <stroke 
            android:width="2dp" 
            android:color="#50999999" />
    
    <stroke 
            android:width="1dp" 
            android:color="#70555555" />
</shape>
```

i did not complete the implementing for android:thumb, so the thumb will be still the original one

Therefore we just have to delete this line again from our layout xml where we define the seekbar

```
android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
```

Comment: Hello, your example works perfect, but I can't add custom thumb for seekbar. Could you do me a favour to show how to add thumb to your example? Thanks!

Answer (score 72):

You should set SeekBar XML properties:

```
<SeekBar 
            ....
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
            ....
/>
```

Where progress is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/background_fill" />

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:drawable="@drawable/progress_fill" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

and thumb is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb_fill" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Hello,
I tried to create above .xml files in drawable folder. but I got this error:  No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/background_fill').  No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/progress_fill').

Comment: Those are drawables that you have to create yourself:you could use 9.png (or another drawable resource - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) to decorate your seekbar as you wish.

Comment: this answer is very much correct :) user357349 must accept it true

Answer (score 29):

Since `SeekBar` uses `colorAccent` by default, you can create a new style with your custom color as `colorAccent` then use `theme` attribute to apply it to the SeekBar.

```
<SeekBar>
    .
    .
    android:theme="@style/MySeekBarTheme"
    .
</SeekBar>
```

in the @style:

```
 <style name="MySeekBarTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar" >
        <item name="colorAccent">#ffff00</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: Thanks ... you saved my lot of effort :)

Answer (score 16):

```
seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
seekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Answer (score 10):

You can just add tint from API level 21.

Add these properties to seekbar element:

> **android:progressTint="@android:color/white"**
>   **android:thumbTint="@android:color/white"**

Final result:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/is"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressTint="@android:color/white"
    android:thumbTint="@android:color/white"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

**1. Create a drawable XML:** 
Name it : *progress_drawable*

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>
> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>   android:shape="line">
>
> <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#fff"/>
>
> </shape>
> ```

**2. Assign it to Seekbar**

```
            <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/slider_1"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:rotation="270" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the accent color of your style

```
<style name="TickMarkSeekBar" parent="Theme.KefTheme">
        <item name="tickMark">@drawable/tickmark</item>
        <item name="thumbTint">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```