# Customizing seekbar in android

Tags: android

I want to customize seekbar in android.

[image]

Can anybody guide me how it can be done? I am new to android.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480456/seek-bar-change-path-color-from-yellow-to-white

Comment: Exactly what kind of customization are you looking for, can you clarify?

Answer (score 18):

```
<SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="34dip"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/strip"
                android:thumb="@drawable/icon_small"
                android:layout_weight="3.0" />
```

You can simply set progressDrawble,thumb and backgroung attribute and you will get all you want.

Comment: And this is an example on how it can be done:
http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/

Answer (score 2):

```
// ------------ custom seekbar
 LayerDrawable layer = (LayerDrawable) verticalSeekBar_1
 .getProgressDrawable();

 Drawable draw1 = (Drawable) layer
 .findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress);

 Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext()
 .getResources(), R.drawable.scroll_on);

 draw1 = new ClipDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap1),
 Gravity.AXIS_PULL_BEFORE, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);

 layer.setDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress, draw1);

 Drawable draw2 = (Drawable) layer
 .findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.background);

 Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext()
 .getResources(), R.drawable.scroll_off);

 draw2 = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap2);
 layer.setDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.background, draw2);

// --------------
```

Comment: Excellent. As the image may come from network. I have to know how to customize seekbar programatically but not in xml.

Answer (score 1):

**XML code**

```
 <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumbler_small"
    android:indeterminate="false" />
```

**seek_bar.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/SecondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/first"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/second"/>
</layer-list>
```

**first drawable is empty or shown not color full area.**

**second drawable is fill or color full area.**

[this](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-use-and-custom-seekbar-in-android.html) link help your more.