# Round corners in a progress bar Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm following that [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android/2021119#2021119) for change the color of a progress bar. The problem is that using that snipplet the corners of the progressbar turns squared. How can I keep the original corners look and change the colors? Thanks in advance

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3480456/367677

Answer (score 1):

Try to assign each corner separately and put pixels instead of DIP, some manufacturers don't implement this feature correctly:

```
android:topLeftRadius="5px"
android:topRightRadius="5px"
android:bottomLeftRadius="5px"
android:bottomRightRadius="5px"
```