# How to change seek bar progress colour according to its progress?

Tags: android, colors, seekbar

I want to create a custom seekbar, whose progress bar's colour change between red and blue as the user changes the progress of the bar.

I have tried it but its only changing the background colour not the progress bar color.

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {


                seekBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED + progress);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use custom seek bar for that requirement see following link's

1. http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/
2. [Seek bar, change path color from yellow to white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480456/seek-bar-change-path-color-from-yellow-to-white)

Answer (score 7):

There are a lot of way to do this, I'll tell the simple way.
You can set the color of progressBackground like this:

```
seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter("<Color you wish>", PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

If your api level 21, you can use getProgressBackgroundTintList or getProgressBackgroundTintMode().

Comment: This doesn't change the tint of the Seekbar progress on pre-Lollipop.

Comment: Does not work at least on my Android 8 device. Any idea why it does not work ?