# How to change the background of a SeekBar?

Tags: android

I would like to change the background color of a SeekBar from yellow (default) to a color I choose but I've only found the method to change the color of the black area around the SeekBar. Can anyone help me????

Comment: see this : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480456/seek-bar-change-path-color-from-yellow-to-white][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480456/seek-bar-change-path-color-from-yellow-to-white

Answer (score 9, accepted):

xmls ( background_fill , progress_fill and progress could look like that for a gradient red

progress xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                <item android:id="@android:id/background" 
android:drawable="@drawable/background_fill" />

                <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
                <clip android:drawable="@drawable/progress_fill" />
                </item>
                </layer-list>
```

background_fill xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
           <gradient android:startColor="#FF555555" android:centerColor="#FF555555"
    android:endColor="#FF555555" android:angle="90" />
            <corners android:radius="5px" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#50999999" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#70555555" />
                </shape>
```

and progress_fill xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
             <gradient android:startColor="#FF470000" android:centerColor="#FFB80000"
    android:endColor="#FFFF4400" android:angle="180" />
             <corners android:radius="5px" />
             <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#50999999" />
             <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#70555555" />
                 </shape>
```

i did not complete the implementing for android:thumb, so the thumb will be still the original one

Therefore we just have to delete this line again from our layout xml where we define the seekbar

```
android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
```

for more info see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480456/seek-bar-change-path-color-from-yellow-to-white)